# Netsuite - Getting object List

Tags: netsuite, rest

I am trying to get all objects using REST API

I have successfully got most of them doing a GET request to:

```
https://...suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/metadata-catalog
```

But in example, a specific object is not arriving: "Partners"

am I missing something in the request?
is this object under a different name?

Answer (score 0):

It's on the list - "name": "partner"

```
        {
            "name": "partner",
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": "canonical",
                    "href": "https://[accountId].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/metadata-catalog/partner",
                    "mediaType": "application/schema+json"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "alternate",
                    "href": "https://[accountId].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/metadata-catalog/partner",
                    "mediaType": "application/swagger+json"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "alternate",
                    "href": "https://[accountId].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/metadata-catalog/partner",
                    "mediaType": "application/schema+json"
                },
                {
                    "rel": "describes",
                    "href": "https://[accountId].suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/partner",
                    "mediaType": "application/json"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Have you enabled anything in particular?

Comment: It is enabled in the account I used for testing. From Help: To use partner records the Partner Relationship Management feature must be enabled at Setup > Enable Features > CRM.